# Display image from a shared folder using XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to display an image from a shared folder but I'm getting error

```
INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION or INVALID QUALIFIED NAME
```

This is the code, here fyi, 160.115 is my machine IP having shared folder "SHARE" which is open to all to read and  write.

```
 ` <xsl:template match="element">
      <img>
       <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="file:\\172.16.160.115\share\german_shepherd_icon.jpg"/>
      </ xsl:attribute>
       </img>
     </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What IDE you use? Visual Studio and Eclipse can debug xslt-transforms

Comment: Could you add some context on how the snippet is used? And: what about that extra space character in the closing tag of `</xsl:attribute>`?

Answer (score 1):

The `select` attribute of `value-of` is an XPath expression, so if you want the value to be a literal string then you'd need to wrap it in quotes (`select="'literal value'"`).  But far simpler would be just to use a literal attribute (note you need forward slashes rather than backward ones as it's a URI):

```
<img src="file://172.16.160.115/share/german_shepherd_icon.jpg"/>
```